# Enforce rule on Sticky to the top of lists

Tags: views, nodes, 8

I have x amount of nodes of content type "job", all of which are presented on page using two views, one that sits at the top "job-highlighted" and one that sits at the bottom "rest-of-jobs".

One job is selected to be displayed in the top view. It is selected using the "Sticky at top of lists" option in the back end.

The rest are displayed in the "rest-of-jobs" view.

The problem is that the user can set a number of jobs to have the sticky at the top of lists selected.

My question is, is there a way to enforce the content type job to have only one node with the sticky at the top of lists functionality. Can I implement a procedure that updates these or is there a module that already introduces this functionality?

Can anyone offer a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the context of [this question](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3619/39516) (on meta.drupal.SE), I wonder why you used the 8-tag in this question. Would you mind (briefly) explaining so please?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a node for the overview page? If so:
Instead of using the sticky to top button add a relationship field to the job overview node and set that to allow 1 value, and show the selected job in the highlight field.

Answer (score 0):

Allow only 1 value in your view "job-highlighted". That should do it for you.

Comment: Hi @Umed, please refrain from posting one-sentence answers. If possibly, provide step-by-step instructions on how to do configure this and maybe add a screenshot of the resulting configuration screen. Thanks!